# Properties of increasingly convex function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{F}$ is strictly increasing, convex, and twice continuously differentiable function. Define $g$ and $h$ as
$$
g(x) = \frac{f(x+1)-f(1)}{f(x)-f(0)},
h(x) = \frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}.
$$
I would like to know whether $h'(x) > 0$ implies either

1. $g(x) \geq g(0)$ for all $x$ or
2. $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \overline{g} > g(0)$ (so that $g(x) \geq g(0)$ for $x \geq \overline{x}$ for some $\overline{x}>0$).

Intuitively, $h'(x)>0$ implies $f'''(x)>0$, i.e. increasing convexity. And this implies that $f(x+1)-f(1)$ increases faster than $f(x)-f(0)$. But I haven't been able to show that it is enough to show that the fraction is increasing as well.

Comment: The first condition isn't true, as you could replace $f(x)$ by $f^*(x)=f(x)+c$ for any constant $c$ and all of the other functions defined would stay the same, but for sufficiently large $c$ you would have $f^*(0)>g(0)$

Comment: Sorry, your comment pointed out a couple of typos I had in the statement. I edited them now.

Comment: $h'=\frac{f'''}{f'}-(\frac{f''}{f'})^2$ gives you a lower bound of $f'''>\frac{(f'')^2}{f'}$ - is this enough for what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the question, I found the solution myself. Let $k(x) = \frac{f'(x+1)}{f'(x)}$. Then $h'>0$ implies that $k$ is strictly increasing, because
$$
  k'(x)
  = \frac{f''(x+1) f'(x) - f''(x) f'(x+1)}{[f'(x)]^2} > 0
  \iff
  \frac{f''(x+1)}{f'(x+1)}  > \frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}.
$$
And now
$$
  g'(x)
  = \frac{f'(x+1)[f(x)-f(0)]-f'(x)[f(x+1)-f(1)]}{[f'(x)]^2}
  > 0
  \iff
  k(x) > g(x).
$$
As $k(z) < k(x)$ for all $z \in [0,x)$ we get that $f'(z+1) < k(x) f'(z)$ and therefore indeed
$$
  g(x) 
  = \frac{\int_0^x f'(z+1) dz}{\int_0^x f'(z) dz}
  < \frac{\int_0^x k(x) f'(z) dz}{\int_0^x f'(z) dz}
  = k(x).
$$
This proves that $g(x)$ is strictly increasing, which implies both claims.